# PyHoca-GUI system tray icon not showing in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: gnome, 20.04, icons, x2go, x2goclient

I have installed `pyhoca-gui` version 0.6.1.1 on Ubuntu 20.04 and after running the program I do not see the icon in the notifications area/systray. The systray icon is the only way to access the program GUI.

I can verify that pyhoca-gui is running: I see it among the running processes and when I try to run it again it says that another instance is running.

Can someone confirm this issue and/or suggest a fix? Thanks.